# Random unwanted favicon being shown on one of my domain

Tags: jquery, html, favicon

How can i remove it ? 
What could be the possible reasons ?
Please have a look at :      http://www.creativecube.pk

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any favicon. Use http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker to check and verify your favicon. Then, use their generator to make favicons for all the devices.